# How do I configure parameters like fuzziness using flask_msearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, flask

I am trying to configure the flask_msearch ES search. I understand that it is not the most popular library but it is quite easy to start with. This is my first time using elasticsearch but I'd like to know if anyone knows how to configure parameter such as fuzziness using this library?

I can search using the query in the w_search function but I am struggling to find how I can configure it. Thank you in advance.

flask_msearch: https://github.com/honmaple/flask-msearch

my code:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'symptom_database'
    __searchable__ = ['symptom']

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    symptom = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post %r>' % self.symptom


# views.py
@app.route("/search", methods = ['GET','POST'])
def w_search():
    form = Post()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        keyword = request.form.get('keyword')
        results = Post.query.msearch(keyword,fields=['symptom']).all()

        print(results, flush=True)


        return ''
    return render_template('search.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES fuzziness search use keyword regexp

Such as:

```
Post.query.msearch("{keyword}*".format(keyword=keyword),fields=['symptom']).all()
# or
Post.query.msearch("symptom:{keyword}*".format(keyword=keyword)).all()
```